# Html.EditorFor does not render view in EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have view model:

```
public class OrderInfoViewModel
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }

        public IList<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

In view /Home/Index.cshtml I have:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.OrderInfoViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Order)

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OrderDetails)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />    
}
```

In view /Home/EditorTemplates/OrderDetail I have:

```
@model MyApp.Model.OrderDetail

@{
    Layout = null;
}

test
```

And view in /Home/EditorTemplates/OrderDetail does not render :( But if I delete IList in class of view model **IList OrderDetails** to **OrderDetail OrderDetails** then it works, why? :(

Comment: Ignore my other comment.  I've just created a new project, using your code and I have no issues.  It works correctly.

Comment: John and you can see also view /Home/EditorTemplates/OrderDetail.cshtml? :O

Comment: Yep, it's calling it properly.

Comment: I've uploaded the project so you can see for yourself (the .zip file has the same name as the ID of your question): https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctp2hmf2mzspqbb/23135145.zip

Comment: John which version visual studio do you have and which version of asp.net mvc? Because I have visual studio express 2012 and asp.net mvc 4.

Comment: That was in VS2010 with ASP.NET MVC 3.  I just repeated the same exact code with VS2013 and MVC 5 and the result is the same.

Comment: OH - I know - I have forgotten initialize list in Controller - thx JOHN !! :) Now it works.